# How to make different activities in android communicate properly and send intents?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

I'm following this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

And trying to send a message between activities.I want the user to enter text in the main activity, press send and have it show up in a different activity.  For some reason, after I play the app on my phone and press the "send" button that's supposed to transfer intent and message content to the next activity - it just shows a blank activity.

I think that I may not have needed to change content_main, as I got a little confused with this xml file and `activity_main` and was not sure where each chunks of code should go.

Current code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**DisplayMessageActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_display_message.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"       android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"
>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why did you write `MainActivity` code into `DisplayMessageActivity ` ??

Comment: Good question! Beginners mistake I guess.. 
Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

in question.

Comment: @RahulSharma he pasted wrong code in DisplayMessageActivity

Answer (score 0):

In the new Activity,i.e `DisplayMessageActivity.java` retrieve those values:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        editText .setText(value)

        }
    }
```

Use this technique to pass variables from one Activity to the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `extraString` in `DisplayMessageActivity`, that you have sent from previous activity `MainActivity`
 try this

```
// try this in onCreate() of DisplayMessageActivity
 String myExtraString = getIntent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
 if(myExtraString == null )
 { // no extraString was attached to the intent 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a `TextView` inside your activity_display_message.xml

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/show_message"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in your DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String message = bundle.getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_message);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```